# Kubernetes cluster-master does not start after libvirt-coreos provisioning (kube-up.sh)

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, coreos, libvirt

I am fairly new to Kubernetes but a long-time Linux sysadm.

I have discovered a problem on an Ubuntu Xenial system, after following the tutorial here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/libvirt-coreos/

**Host Machine background:**

```
[core@kvmhost Automation]$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**Get Kubernetes and deploy a cluster (Success):**

```
[core@kvmhost Automation]$ export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=libvirt-coreos; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   161  100   161    0     0    232      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   232
100     7  100     7    0     0      7      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01     0
Downloading kubernetes release v1.5.2
  from https://dl.k8s.io/v1.5.2/kubernetes.tar.gz
  to /mnt/largevol/Automation/kubernetes.tar.gz
Is this ok? [Y]/n
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   161  100   161    0     0    240      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   240
100 4682k  100 4682k    0     0  3925k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 17.5M
Unpacking kubernetes release v1.5.2
Kubernetes release: v1.5.2
Server: linux/amd64  (to override, set KUBERNETES_SERVER_ARCH)
Client: linux/amd64  (autodetected)

Will download kubernetes-server-linux-amd64.tar.gz from https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.5.2
Will download and extract kubernetes-client-linux-amd64.tar.gz from https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.5.2
Is this ok? [Y]/n
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  299M  100  299M    0     0  16.9M      0  0:00:17  0:00:17 --:--:-- 18.5M

md5sum(kubernetes-server-linux-amd64.tar.gz)=7947bd430c4ffc358a6784e51c1d2b0f
sha1sum(kubernetes-server-linux-amd64.tar.gz)=4dbdcfa623412dac6be8fd5a4209a1f1423e8d30

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.2M  100 22.2M    0     0  12.4M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.4M

md5sum(kubernetes-client-linux-amd64.tar.gz)=bca61eea6c0ddc5a5c771ac4d01cf784
sha1sum(kubernetes-client-linux-amd64.tar.gz)=081c096636f3f262b0e494dc496d97e67bc6c3db

Extracting /mnt/largevol/Automation/kubernetes/client/kubernetes-client-linux-amd64.tar.gz into /mnt/largevol/Automation/kubernetes/platforms/linux/amd64
Add '/mnt/largevol/Automation/kubernetes/client/bin' to your PATH to use newly-installed binaries.
```

**Fire-up our cluster (Fail):**

```
[core@kvmhost Automation]$ cd kubernetes/
[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ echo "POOL_PATH=\"/mnt/largevol/Automation/images/\"" >> cluster/libvirt-coreos/config-default.sh
[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ cluster/kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: libvirt-coreos
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling verify-kube-binaries
... calling kube-up
KUBE_MASTER_IP: 192.168.10.1
KUBE_MASTER: kubernetes-master
Pool kubernetes created

--2017-02-13 01:03:49--  https://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/coreos_production_qemu_image.img.bz2
Resolving alpha.release.core-os.net (alpha.release.core-os.net)... 104.16.20.26, 104.16.21.26, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:141a, ...
Connecting to alpha.release.core-os.net (alpha.release.core-os.net)|104.16.20.26|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 278995186 (266M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cluster/../cluster/../cluster/libvirt-coreos/coreos_production_qemu_image.img.bz2’

coreos_production_qemu_image. 100%[=================================================>] 266.07M  19.0MB/s    in 14s

2017-02-13 01:04:03 (19.0 MB/s) - ‘cluster/../cluster/../cluster/libvirt-coreos/coreos_production_qemu_image.img.bz2’ saved [278995186/278995186]


Vol coreos_base.img created


Pool kubernetes refreshed

TLS assets generated...
Network kubernetes_global created from cluster/../cluster/../cluster/libvirt-coreos/network_kubernetes_global.xml

Network kubernetes_pods created from cluster/../cluster/../cluster/libvirt-coreos/network_kubernetes_pods.xml

Vol kubernetes-node-1.img created

Pool kubernetes refreshed

Domain kubernetes-node-1 created from /tmp/tmp.Uak23Z1JIQ

Vol kubernetes-node-2.img created

Pool kubernetes refreshed

Domain kubernetes-node-2 created from /tmp/tmp.8TC3eDjEwK

Vol kubernetes-node-3.img created

Pool kubernetes refreshed

Domain kubernetes-node-3 created from /tmp/tmp.MYRaUwdpBw

Vol kubernetes-master.img created

Pool kubernetes refreshed

Domain kubernetes-master created from /tmp/tmp.2C2JUbH993

Cluster "libvirt-coreos" set.
User "libvirt-coreos" set.
Context "libvirt-coreos" set.
Switched to context "libvirt-coreos".
Wrote config for libvirt-coreos to /home/core/.kube/config
Wait for cluster readiness
Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3
Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3
Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3

--8<-- REPEATED MANY TIMES BUT CLUSTER IS NEVER READY--8<--

Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3
Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3
Nb ready nodes: 0 / 3
```

**Let's log in to our master node and see what's up:**

```
[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ ssh 192.168.10.1

The authenticity of host '192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:yZ1rw8WV0ECdep3TDEydnznx8S5TagdvZEVoWtNaHK0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.10.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Container Linux by CoreOS alpha (1313.0.0)
core@kubernetes-master ~ $ cd /opt/kubernetes/bin/
core@kubernetes-master /opt/kubernetes/bin $ ls -l

ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

core@kubernetes-master /opt/kubernetes/bin $ cd ..
core@kubernetes-master /opt/kubernetes $ ls -l

total 16
drwxrwxr-x. 2 core core 4096 Feb 13 01:04 addons
drwxr-x---. 2 core core 4096 Jan 12 05:08 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 2 core core 4096 Feb 13 01:04 certs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 core core 4096 Feb 13 01:04 manifests

core@kubernetes-master /opt/kubernetes $ id

uid=500(core) gid=500(core) groups=500(core),10(wheel),233(docker),248(systemd-journal),250(portage),251(rkt),253(fleet) context=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0

core@kubernetes-master /opt/kubernetes $
```

**Summary:**

Our cluster is successfully deployed (master plus 3 nodes) but the kube-apiserver process cannot start due to file access permissions.

**Workaround (change the permission of the 9p filesystem to provide a+rx):**

```
[core@kvmhost bin]$ cd /mnt/largevol/Automation/images/kubernetes/
[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ chmod -R a+rx bin
[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ virsh reboot kubernetes-master
Domain kubernetes-master is being rebooted

[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ virsh reboot kubernetes-node-1
Domain kubernetes-node-1 is being rebooted

[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ virsh reboot kubernetes-node-2
Domain kubernetes-node-2 is being rebooted

[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ virsh reboot kubernetes-node-3
Domain kubernetes-node-3 is being rebooted

[core@kvmhost kubernetes]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://192.168.10.1:8080
KubeDNS is running at http://192.168.10.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

**Question:**

- Why can't the libvirt guest see the files? The files are owned by ID 500 which matches UID of the CoreOS user.
- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was directed here by k8sport, but I see this question is 6 months old; is it still a problem?

Comment: 1.5.2 is practically prehistoric in "kubernetes years"; have you tried it with a modern version?

Comment: But while I don't have a libvirt setup to test with, when I see that kind of uid-permission mismatch, I think "volume mount"; have you checked to see if that directory is a mount (volume mount, nfs mount, other weird non-local-directory type stuff)?